# Remove a dot added by `unlist()` and replace it with "/" in a string vector in R

Tags: r, string, function, loops, tidyverse

I was wondering how to turn my `in`put into my desired `out`put?

As you can see, `unlist()` adds a `.` so only the `.` by `unlist()` must be removed not ANY other `.` and replaced with `/`.

```
in <- list(a.study = c(scale.1 = TRUE, outcome = FALSE), scale.1 = c(a.study = FALSE, outcome = FALSE))


out <- unlist(Filter(length,lapply(names(in),function(i) names(which(unlist(in[i]) == TRUE)))))

# [1] "a.study.scale.1" # Current output

desired_output <- c("a.study/scale.1")  # Desired output
```

Comment: you happy to use str_replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the setup a bit:

```
unlist(Filter(
  length,
  lapply(
    names(input), 
    \(i) {
      k <- which(input[[i]])
      if (length(k)) paste0(i, '/', names(input[[i]])[k])
    }
  )
))

[1] "a.study/scale.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```r
library(tidyverse)

inp <- list(a.study = c(scale.1 = TRUE, outcome = FALSE), scale.1 = c(a.study = FALSE, outcome = FALSE))

out <- unlist(Filter(length,lapply(names(inp),function(i) names(which(unlist(inp[i]) == TRUE)))))

out %>% 
  str_replace("(?<=y)\\.(?=s)", "\\/")

#> [1] "a.study/scale.1"
```